# Finding 1 and only 1 character, Python

Tags: python, loops, search, glob

I have many files named file_1, file_2, another_file_1, another_file_2 etc.

How can I find the files which end with 1 and only 1.

At the moment I'm using the `glob` function in a loop, such as

```
for i in range(len(number_of_files)):
    files = glob.glob("*" + str(i+1) + ".txt")
```

The problem is that this gives me the files called 1, 11, 21, 31, etc. I only want file 1 one time, file 11 one time and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your wildcard matcher is matching absolutely anything up until it finds `(i+1).txt`

If you know all of your files are in the format `foo_bar_1.txt` where there is an underscore before the file number, you could use this matcher: `glob.glob('*_' + str(i + 1) + '.txt')` and it would only return what you're looking for.

Comment: Glad that I could help!